# Understanding VC++ project/solution explorer file hierarchy

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I took a C++ project done by someone in VC++ and I opened the project on my machine. When I opened the project in VC++, I could see the source files organised in directories: Presenter, View and some file directly under Source Files. These presenter and view directories are seen only in the VC++ project explorer and not in windows file explorer. So I have this basic function: How does VC++ organise the source files in the given project. Also some of my source files are not visible in the VC++ solution explorer while they are seen on the windows file explorer. What could be reason behind that? (While building the code, I get some linking errors due to the functions implemented in these missing .cpp files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as it turns out the organization of source files in Visual Studio is not synced, mirrored, or reflected in the Windows file explorer. If you go to the `Solution Explorer` pane and try to add a new folder (`Add` -> `New Solution Folder`) you'll notice that it's a new "Solution Folder" that you're adding, not a new folder on the OS. If you have files that you want to add, you'll also have to explicitly right-click and select `Add` -> `Existing Item...`, or as [dvasanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300758/dvasanth) suggested, you can edit the `*.vcxproj` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly edit the .vcxproj file to add or remove files & change the project settings. This file is organized in XML format & fairly easy to understand.

Comment: Is it <projectName>.vcxproj file? Would that explain the missing files too?